# Vector push back error

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using C++ to implement FP-growth algorithm, but I get some errors when using vector. Here is my code:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    FPData *fpData;
    int childCount;
    struct Node *parent;
    vector<Node*> childs;
}FPNode;

FPNode* FPTree::NewNode(string data, int support)
{
    FPNode *node = (FPNode*) malloc(sizeof(FPNode));
    FPData *fpData = (FPData*) malloc(sizeof(FPData));
    fpData -> data = data;
    fpData -> support = support;
    node -> fpData = fpData;
    node -> childCount = 0;
    node -> parent = NULL;
    return node;
}
void FPTree::InsertFPPath(FPNode* root, list<FPData*> fpDatas)
{
    if(fpDatas.size() <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    bool flag = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < root -> childCount; i++)
    {
        FPNode* child = root -> childs[i];
        if(child -> fpData -> data == fpDatas.front() -> data)
        {
           flag = false;
           child -> fpData -> support ++;
           fpDatas.pop_front();
           InsertFPPath(child, fpDatas);
           break;
        }
    }
    if(flag)
    {
        FPData* firstData = fpDatas.front();
        FPNode* newChild = NewNode(firstData -> data, firstData -> support);
        root -> childs.push_back(newChild);   // error at here
        root -> childCount ++;
        fpDatas.pop_front();
        for(int i = 0; i < fpDatas.size(); i++)
        {

            InsertFPPath(newChild, fpDatas);
        }
     }
}
```

The `InsertFPPath()` is a recursive method, I get error when second iterate:

```
root -> childs.push_back(newChild)
```

The error comes at:

```
 construct(_Up* __p, _Args&&... __args)  // here the __p is null, and __args is right
 {
      ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
 }
```

And the thread Queue stop at:

```
#0  0x00000001000050cf in void std::__1::allocator::construct(Node**, Node* const&&&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1673
```

the backtrace is :

```
#0  0x00000001000050cf in void std::__1::allocator::construct(Node**, Node* const&&&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1673
#1  0x00000001000050bc in void std::__1::allocator_traits >::__construct(std::__1::integral_constant, std::__1::allocator&, Node**, Node* const&&&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1600
#2  0x000000010000509c in void std::__1::allocator_traits >::construct(std::__1::allocator&, Node**, Node* const&&&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1453
#3  0x0000000100005079 in std::__1::vector >::push_back(Node* const&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1590
#4  0x0000000100004fa9 in FPTree::InsertFPPath(Node*, std::__1::list >) at /Users/dorothy/ME/USTC/作业/数据挖掘/experiment/FPTree/FPTree/FPTree.cpp:129
#5  0x00000001000051b4 in FPTree::InsertFPPath(Node*, std::__1::list >) at /Users/dorothy/ME/USTC/作业/数据挖掘/experiment/FPTree/FPTree/FPTree.cpp:135**
```

Comment: What error? Please be specific.

Comment: Why do you keep track of `childCount` while you can get the `size()` of childs? Also, when iterating over an `std::vector` you should use iterators, instead of indexed access.

Comment: @user2435797 Your C++ looks a lot like C. Pick one and stick to it.

Comment: If you're programming C++, why are you using `typedef` for a structure? A structure is basically the same as a class, so the structure name can be used as a type.

Comment: Also, the line you say give you the error doesn't exist in the code you show, and it doesn't match the structure you show either. And please *show us the actual error*! Copy the complete build-log and paste it in the question *as text*, then tell us where in *your* code the errors is, for example by adding a comment in the code you show.

Comment: I'm a novice in C++...

Comment: @user2435797 `list<FPData*> fpDatas`  You are passing a `std::list` by value, meaning that the function is working with a local copy and not the actual `std::list` you passed in.  Is this what you actually intended to do?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah, after copy it, I pass the data to FPNode and new it.  Thank you for your reply

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have updated the error.

Comment: @user2435797 You need to show the full backtrace so we know where the crash happens in *your* code.

Comment: @ajshort  the error is updated.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I have updated my backtrace. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Now to the big question: What is the value of `root` and where does it point when the crash happens?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I have debug into it, and find the value of root is normal...It points to a FPNode.   All args are normal , just __p is `construct(_Up* __p, _Args&&... __args) `  is NULL, maybe because allocate memory failed? but I have no ideas why it failed...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: A (possible) unrelated question,. why do you need the separate `childCount` variable? You have the exact count in the `childs` vector. Have you checked that the counts are synchronized? Also, what does `NewNode` do? Can you show it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I use array instead of vector before, so I need childCounts to get the size of array... I didn't remove it after changed to vector...I should remove it later..  I have updated the code and show the implementation of `NewNode`

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate memory for structures (`struct` or `class`) containing constructors, or for structures containing objects that have constructors, then you can't allocate the memory using `malloc`. The `malloc` function only allocates memory, but it doesn't call the constructors, and in your case that means that the `childs` member object will not be constructed and using the vector will lead to *undefined behavior*.

When allocating memory dynamically in C++ you need to use the `new` operator:

```
FPNode *node = new FPNode;
FPData *fpData = new FPData;
```